# SQL Query for showing dates not stored in the table

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in which i am storing dates and other information.

I wanna display the records for the dates which are not stored in the table.

Eg.. i have dates `01/01/2012[dd/mm/yyyy]` , `03/01/2012` ,  `06/01/2012`.

I wanna show the output for the dates `02/01/2012` ,`04/05/2012` , `05/01/2012.`

Query for this please in **SQLServer2008**

Comment: please provide the table structure

Comment: provide structure and also what u have tried yet ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DATEADD` function. For example, to add 1 day to current date:

```
SELECT DATEADD(dd, 1, GETDATE())
```

You can find more information on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH MYCTE AS
(
SELECT CAST('1900-01-01' AS DATETIME) DateValue
UNION ALL
SELECT DateValue + 1
FROM MYCTE 
WHERE DateValue + 1 < '3550-12-31'
)

SELECT DateValue, B.SomeColumn
FROM MYCTE A
LEFT JOIN MyTable B ON A.DateValue = B.DateValue
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

I got the date range cte from [here](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamiethomson/archive/2007/01/11/T_2D00_SQL_3A00_-Generate-a-list-of-dates.aspx) (and it takes 4 seconds to generate a table of 250000 rows)

Answer (score 0):

This code displays all dates from 2011 year missing in your table:

```
create table #dates (d datetime);
declare @start_period datetime;
set @start_period='01.01.2011'; 
declare @end_period datetime;
set @end_period='01.01.2012';

declare @d datetime;
set @d=@start_period

while(@d<@end_period)
begin
   insert into #dates (d) values (@d)
   SET @d=@d+1
end
select d from #dates where d not in (select <date> from <your_table>)
```